# What is my lecturer saying here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, projectile-motion

My lecturer gave us some exercises on Dynamics with explained solutions in case we get stuck. One of the exercises is this:

> A particle of mass $\space m \space$ is attached to the end of a light inelastic string of length $\space a \space$, the other end being fixed.
>
> Initially, the particle hangs freely vertically below the fixed end, and is given a horizontal velocity $\space u \space$. After the string has turned through an angle $\space \theta \space$, show that the tension in the string is:
>
> $$ m \left[g \left (3 \cos{\theta} - 2 \right) + {{u^2}\over a} \right]$$

My lecturer handwrites the solutions. Here is a snippet of what he wrote and what confuses me:

[image]

Notice how he subbed the $\space \ddot{r} \space$ with velocity $\space u \space$, but also subbed $\space {d \dot{\theta} \over dt} \space$ with velocity $\space u \space$.

Also, I can't tell whether he wrote $\space u \space$ or $\space \dot{u} \space$. If it's the latter, isn't $\space u \space$ just a constant and not a velocity function of time? Hence making the act of dotting it pointless?

Sorry for the overload of questions, I'm really stuck. I much rather prefer typed notes to avoid issues like this.

Comment: $u$ is not a constant, it changes in time though acceleration due to gravity

Comment: @JohnDoe - Ahh thank you, I feel so stupid haha. So did my lecturer write $\space \dot{u} \space$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I pointed out in another answer, your lecturer seems to be writing "i.e."

You claimed that in the second of your confusions that he replaced $\frac{d\dot\theta}{dt}$ with $u$. This is not what happens in that step. Here is what happens: $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\frac {\cancel{m}}{r}\frac d{dt} (r^2\dot\theta)\hat\theta&=\cancel mg\sin(\theta)\hat\theta\\\frac 1r(2r\dot r\dot\theta+r^2\ddot\theta)&=g\sin\theta\\2\dot r\dot \theta+r\ddot\theta&=g\sin\theta\\\end{align}$$
Then if you use the fact that $r=a$ does not chance then $\dot r=0$, and this gives $$a\ddot\theta=g\sin\theta$$ which is what your lecturer looks to have written.

Also as I wrote in a comment of that answer, later in the text, the lecturer uses 9.15 in 9.13, and there is no trace of $u$ or $\dot u$. Finally, looking at the way your lecturer wrote $u$ in the last line suggests that he does not write it with a curl at the end, as all the circled ones have. So the circled ones appear to say i.e.

Comment: Thank you. Really helped clear things up.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I cannot comment but I think that what you circled in red is simply the Latin abbreviation *ie* which corresponds to *id est*. It means something like *that is to say* and is used to explain or clarify something. See the [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/i.e.) for more informations.

Comment: It is clearly not that @M.P. In eq. (9.13) he clearly uses $u : = \dot{r}$

Comment: Actually @RafaelWagner I changed my mind. Later in the text, the lecturer uses 9.15 in 9.13, and there is no trace of $u$ or $\dot u$

Comment: I never said that all the time you have the letter u it corresponds to *ie*. I only said that it corresponds to *ie* when it is circled in red.

Comment: Yes, sorry, there is no sense using $u := \dot{r}$, if it is velocity should be $u := a\dot{\theta}$ and then the lecturer would be wrong.

Comment: This is the worst i.e. ever